# XSL sort in XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have this script to count some values o prodicts. It works perfect. How can I use `order="descending"` or `<xsl:sort>`

**XML**

```
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Lahůdková cibulka</NAME>
    <CODE>89</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>3</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Rané brambory 1 kg</NAME>
    <CODE>4</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>15</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Kapusta</NAME>
    <CODE>93</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>30</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Bílé zelí</NAME>
    <CODE>20</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
```

I would like to sort in alphabetical order by name like this:

**PREFERED XML**

```
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Bílé zelí</NAME>
    <CODE>20</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Kapusta</NAME>
    <CODE>93</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>30</AMOUNT>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Lahůdková cibulka</NAME>
    <CODE>89</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>3</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Rané brambory 1 kg</NAME>
    <CODE>4</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>15</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
```

I use this XSLT. Where can I put the sorting parameter?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="itemkey" match="ITEM" use="concat(NAME, CODE)"/>
<xsl:template match="/ORDERS">
  <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemkey', concat(NAME, CODE))[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ITEM">   
    <xsl:copy>      
        <xsl:variable name="curr-group" select="key('itemkey', concat(NAME, CODE))" />  
       <xsl:copy-of select="CODE|NAME"/>        
        <AMOUNT>         
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($curr-group/AMOUNT)"/>        
        </AMOUNT>       
    </xsl:copy>         
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `xsl:sort` as a child of `xsl:apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemkey', concat(NAME, CODE))[1])]">
  <xsl:sort select="NAME"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Thank you. I try this, but after it there is some error `Warning: simplexml_load_file(): https://tisk.pesema.cz/zbozi/xml-patek.php:2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /data/web/virtuals/76197/virtual/www/subdom/tisk/zbozi/zbozi_patek.php on line 3`

`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <b>Warning</b>: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: copy line in /data/web/virtuals/76197/virtual/www/subdom/tisk/zbozi/zbozi_patek.php on line 3`

`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /data/web/virtuals/76197/virtual/www/subdom/tisk/zbozi/zbozi_patek.php on line 3`

Comment: I can't explain that, your posted code with my above change suggested in the answer works fine at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Mvnt3k.